# Compare two tables dynamically in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Please consider we have two tables
`Table1` with (3 columns)
`Table2` with same 3 columns.

To find the new records that are in `Table2`, but not in `Table1`, we will be using the following code.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 AS T2
WHERE (((Exists (SELECT *
        FROM
           Table1 T1
        WHERE
           T1.Field1 = T2.Field1 AND
           T1.Field2 = T2.Field2 AND
           T1.Field3 = T2.Field3))=False));
```

But, what if we don't know the number of columns in table? how can we write a generalized code or something like a forloop to compare all the columns in the table and find the new records in Table2 that are not  in table1? Please help me. I'm stuck.

Comment: What do you have MS Sql-Server or Access?

Comment: Actually you can inner join to find out the ones that don't have matches. If you don't know the number of columns then you are going to have to craft your sql to use only the known fields.

Answer (score 0):

When you inner join you are specifying only matches from both tables. You can find only the matches with:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.field1 = t1.field1 
                    AND t2.field2 = t1.field2
                    AND t3.field3 = t1.field3
```

This query should return 6 columns.

Typically you should only need to join on keys and so the disparate columns names should matter as long as the intent behind the keys matches.